Do I need to check whether the value is null or not in my code in Go?
I am using the code below to delete the sqs message in the client side.
if resp, err := s.client.DeleteMessageBatch(context.TODO(), &sqs.DeleteMessageBatchInput{
    Entries:  entries,
    QueueUrl: s.url,
}); err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("failed to DeleteMessageBatch, %v, %v", err, resp.Failed)
}

Since you don't need to see the whole code, so I wrote the part of the code.
As you can see, I called the DeleteMessageBatchInput and printed the error message when err is not nil.
Suppose that there are some network issues while calling it, then err is not the nil.
In this case, resp.Failed can have null value so that it caused the memory issue?
If so, do I have to write some defensive code for above case?
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Generally then convention is that when and error is returned the rest of the values are invalid. If you look at the code, you get returned either an error or an result:
    result, err := ...
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    ...

    return result, nil

and this would usually be true for any sane code you encounter.
So you don't have to test resp for anything in an error case, you shouldn't use it at all. Your code will inevitably panic with a null pointer exception.
The documentation says that you should check for batch errors for an successful call to Client.DeleteMessageBatch. If the call failed you can't really say, since it's unclear where the error happened (for example the batch could have been successful, but you didn't receive a response due to a network error).
If you would have slightly more sophisticated error handling, you could return an error that show that either the whole operation failed or which entries are affected.
For a partial failure define you own error type, for example:
type EntryDeletionError struct {
    Failed []types.BatchResultErrorEntry
}

func (e EntryDeletionError) Error() string {
    var b strings.Builder

    b.WriteString("deletion failed for: ")
    first := true
    for _, f := range e.Failed {
        if first {
            b.WriteString(", ")
            first = false
        }
        b.WriteString(*f.Id)
    }

    return b.String()
}

and then use that in your function:
    resp, err := s.client.DeleteMessageBatch(ctx, &sqs.DeleteMessageBatchInput{
        Entries:  entries,
        QueueUrl: s.url,
    })

    switch {
    case err != nil:
        return fmt.Errorf("deleting entries failed: %w", err)

    case len(resp.Failed) > 0:
        return EntryDeletionError{resp.Failed}
    }

    return nil

Note that you should wrap an enriched error with %w, not %v.

See DeleteMessageBatch.
Failed has two situation.
First http 200 and Failed array in resp.
Second http not 200 and only get errors.
So you can write like this
resp, err := s.client.DeleteMessageBatch(context.TODO(), &sqs.DeleteMessageBatchInput{
    Entries:  entries,
    QueueUrl: s.url,
})
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("failed to DeleteMessageBatch, %v", err)
}
if len(resp.Failed) > 0 {
    return fmt.Errorf("failed to DeleteMessageBatch, %v", resp.Failed)
}

